# Is quick help available in colab notebook when using swift or swift for tensorflow?

Tags: google-colaboratory, swift-for-tensorflow

As in working with python in notebook, you can do this to get help

```
??gradient
```

or

```
gradient??
```

But this doesn't work with swift:

```
error: <Cell 8>:1:1: error: '??' is not a prefix unary operator
??gradient
```

Since "?" is used in swift to mean Optional, there may be a conflict. The project is early, but just to see if anyone know quick help is available, maybe going under a different syntax?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any such a functionality (yet) in the [Swift-Jupyter](https://github.com/google/swift-jupyter) project.

Comment: Indeed, no such functionality exists yet! We plan to eventually provide access to documentation in jupyter (and colab) somehow. Here's a [ticket](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/TF-142) tracking progress.